How does one read the input values in a single line to a bash script without using the "read" keyword?
I have a script that looks like the following:
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: viewer.sh <file>


counter=1
while [ $counter -le $# ]
 do
  string1="$"
  FILE="$counter"
  string3="$FILE"
  string2="$2"
  echo "$string2"
  echo "$FILE, $string3, $string2"
  ((counter++))
done  

Unfortunately the output of the echo lines are 1,1 and 2,2 instead of "sample.txt" and "sample1.txt"  when the input is "./viewer.sh  "sample.txt" "sample1.txt"". How do I print the file names corresponding to the counters instead of counters themselves?

please update the question to show an example with 3-4 inputs, the (wrong) output generated by your script, and the (correct) expected output; your comments about what what you're seeing (1,1 and 2,2), and what you want to see (sample.txt and sampl1.txt) do not match what the pair of echo commands are supposed to print on each pass through the loop so it's not clear (to me) exactly what you're trying to accomplish on each pass through the loop

Are you trying to read input or command-line arguments?  These are not at all the same thing.

Does string1="$" contain a typo?  Did you maybe mean string1="$1"?  And did you mean to use string1 anywhere, or is that just superfluous?

This question is similar to: How to get the nth positional argument in bash?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You don't even need the counter. Just iterate over "$@" directly.
counter=1
for file in "$@"; do
    echo "$counter, $file"
    ((counter++))  # counter=$((counter + 1)) for POSIX compatibility
done


That's what I did eventually but I wanted to know how to create a positional variable using counter.

$ cat viewer.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage: viewer.sh <file>

for (( counter=1; counter <= $#; counter++ )); do
    file="${!counter}"
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done


$ ./viewer.sh "sample.txt" "sample1.txt"
sample.txt
sample1.txt

See What is indirect expansion? What does ${!var*} mean? for what file="${!counter}" does.

There are a lot of ways to slice-n-dice this based on your real requirements. A few ideas ...
You can loop through the inputs, assigning the first one to your variable, then shift the inputs so on the next pass through the loop you read the next input, eg:
$ cat reader.sh
#!/bin/bash

maxcount=$#

for ((counter=1; counter<=maxcount; counter++))
do
    file="$1"
    echo "${counter} : ${file}"
    shift
done

Taking for a test drive:
$ ./viewer.sh sample.txt sample1.txt 'another sample.txt' last_sample.txt
1 : sample.txt
2 : sample1.txt
3 : another sample.txt
4 : last_sample.txt

Keep in mind that upon exiting the loop your input ($@) will be empty so if you need to re-process the input you'll need to look at a different solution, eg, storing the inputs in an array while parsing them:
#!/bin/bash

maxcount=$#
inputs=()

for ((counter=1; counter<=maxcount; counter++))
do
    file="$1"
    inputs+=( "${file}" )
    echo "${counter} : ${file}"
    shift
done

typeset -p inputs

Taking for a test drive:
$ ./viewer.sh sample.txt sample1.txt 'another sample.txt' last_sample.txt
1 : sample.txt
2 : sample1.txt
3 : another sample.txt
4 : last_sample.txt
declare -a inputs=([0]="sample.txt" [1]="sample1.txt" [2]="another sample.txt" [3]="last_sample.txt")

Then again you can immediately load into an array without the need of a loop and shift'ing of inputs.
#!/bin/bash

inputs=( place_holder)        # assumes you want input indices to start with 1
inputs+=( "$@" )

typeset -p inputs

for ((counter=1; counter<=$#; counter++))
do
    echo "${counter} : ${inputs[counter]}"
done

Taking for a test drive:
$ ./viewer.sh sample.txt sample1.txt 'another sample.txt' last_sample.txt
declare -a inputs=([0]="place_holder" [1]="sample.txt" [2]="sample1.txt" [3]="another sample.txt" [4]="last_sample.txt")
1 : sample.txt
2 : sample1.txt
3 : another sample.txt
4 : last_sample.txt


To get parameters by index use
echo "${!counter}"

